# Xcode link matlab dylib: No Info.plist file

Tags: c++, xcode, matlab, dylib, mcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mextest.h"

using namespace std;

int run_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0);
    mextestInitialize();
    mwArray a(1,1,mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwArray b(1,1,mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    a(1,1) = 30.1;
    mextest(1,b,a);
    double* res = new double;
    b.GetData(res,1);
    cout << *res << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    mclmcrInitialize();
    return mclRunMain((mclMainFcnType)run_main, 0, NULL);
}
```

I have installed matlab runtime dylibs and included them to my Xcode projects.
When I built it, I got no error.
However, When I run it, I get:

No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting

And I have no idea what to do.